# How to apply new page layout to all existing pages in a site?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, deployment, powershell, page-layout

I really need your help.

I've created a new page layout in SharePoint Designer 2010 and I want to apply it to all existing pages in a site. Another thing to note, some subsites and pages use different page layouts. If possible I would like to standardize all page layouts.

I checked online and I found some methods but it seems all of them require the page layout to be "un-customized" and deployed using Visual Studio. I've developed the whole layout in SP Designer and I have no clue how to move it to Visual Studio 2010. Is there any way I can do this using Powershell commands or any other tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this post where this can be achieved through PowerShell - http://jakejacobsen.wordpress.com/2011/04/06/powershell-script-for-updating-page-layouts-in-a-site-collection/

Answer (score 3):

Pages are nothing more than an ASPX file. The page layout is in its metadata:

```
<mso:PublishingPageLayout msdt:dt="string">http://server/site/Library/_catalogs/masterpage/PageLayout.aspx, PageLayout</mso:PublishingPageLayout>
```

You can try to donwload all of the aspx files and replace the the infomration above.

Comment: Actually I would phrase it as exactly the opposite. Pages are nothing more than metadata, the Layout is the ASPX file. The entry in the Pages library is more or less a stub file. Publishing Pages are closer to Wiki Pages than to actual documents.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply an existing Page Layout to all pages that already exist (and are assigned to other page layouts) you could do this in a C# console application, or PowerShell.

MSDN has an example of doing exactly this in C#.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishingpage.layout.aspx

The code provided is all you'd need for a static class. In a console application, you'd just need to make sure this code is in a file separate to the Main.cs file, and call into that method.